How to move an aruco marker in Gazebo Garden
I am working on precision landing using PX4 and ROS2, I am able to land on static targets in simulation but I would like to try landing on moving targets. Is there any way to make the aruco marker move in Gazebo using a bridge and the pose of the tag or something similar?
